# Spring boot disable Redis Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I need to disable redis in my Spring Boot Application.
I followed a lot of tips from the web,but without success.

My application.properties,it has this line :

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration

spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false
```

And when i attempt to start my app i get :

**Description**:

Field sessionRepository in org.springframework.session.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.SessionRepository' that could not be found.

**Action:**

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.SessionRepository' in your configuration.

The app i am running it s a Test about WebSocket.It works great,but for business things i need to disable Redis.
Please,any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Here my code:
    **My Main Class:**

```
public class WebSocketChatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {         
SpringApplication.run(WebSocketChatApplication.class, args);    
} 

@Override   protected SpringApplicationBuilder 
   configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {        return 
  return application.sources(WebSocketChatApplication.class);   } 
}
```

**Here my ChatConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ChatProperties.class)
 public class ChatConfig {

@Autowired
private ChatProperties chatProperties;

@Bean
@Description("Tracks user presence (join / leave) and broacasts it to all connected users")
public PresenceEventListener presenceEventListener(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate) {
    PresenceEventListener presence = new PresenceEventListener(messagingTemplate, participantRepository());
    presence.setLoginDestination(chatProperties.getDestinations().getLogin());
    presence.setLogoutDestination(chatProperties.getDestinations().getLogout());
    return presence;
}

@Bean
@Description("Keeps connected users")
public ParticipantRepository participantRepository() {
    return new ParticipantRepository();
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Description("Keeps track of the level of profanity of a websocket session")
public SessionProfanity sessionProfanity() {
    return new SessionProfanity(chatProperties.getMaxProfanityLevel());
}

@Bean
@Description("Utility class to check the number of profanities and filter them")
public ProfanityChecker profanityFilter() {
    ProfanityChecker checker = new ProfanityChecker();
    checker.setProfanities(chatProperties.getDisallowedWords());
    return checker;
}

/*@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
@Description("Embedded Redis used by Spring Session")
public RedisServer redisServer(@Value("${redis.embedded.port}") int port)  throws IOException {
    return new RedisServer(port);
}*/
```

}

**Here my WebSocketConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker


public class WebSocketConfig extends 
AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session> {



@Override
protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
    //registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

**SecurityConfig Class :**

```
@EnableWebSecurity

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "rockandroll";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/index.html")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/chat.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/lib/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/index.html", "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/websocket").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());


}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD.equals(token.getCredentials()) ? 
                                                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN") : null;

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getName(), token.getCredentials(), authorities);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I think this is the most important.The rest is a RestController and  couple of DTO Objects.
Like i already say,it works great,but i need to disable Redis.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Are you using Maven or Gradle? Could you provide the pom.xml or equivalent so that it is easier to understand which libraries are being loaded in classpath? Spring boot uses convention over configuration so it might be something that is being loaded by the libraries you are using

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I implemented JDBC in memory session and it s working great.
Theres 1 thing i dont understand.
About sessions,When i need them and when not?
Because Spring boot,gives you the chance to choose Session Type = none.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a question as a new question or as a comment somewhere else, not as an answer.

Comment: @GuiRitter NO no no

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable the [Redis auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.html) from the Spring boot application class to see if you have any different behaviour.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RedisAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: No ,the same !And if i add spring.session.store-type=none,the same.Thanks!

Comment: Can you enhance your question with your relevant code so that it is easier to understand where the problem might be? It might be many things. The exception seems to point to a problem in Spring Session but not sure